# Find the distance between lines that beside each other with coordinates as vertex with the same starting point

Tags: python, algorithm, distance, path-finding

Hello Im new in python and i need help. First of all, Sorry for my english as it not my first language.

I want to find distance between lines. If the line are less than 0.2 or more than 0.3 between each other. It will return an error log.
For starter I have four path,

```
paths=[Path_A, Path_D, Path_C, Path_D]
Path_A =[
                    [101.66727417501791, 3.0590027072577914],
                    [101.66727830182118, 3.0589505710261693],
                    [101.66721266342564, 3.0589509682277645],
                    [101.66719249835002, 3.058978143007745],
                    [101.66715661762409, 3.0589486835991733],
]
Path_B= [
                    [101.66727417501791, 3.0590027072577914],
                    [101.66726593060882, 3.0589642020922305],
                    [101.66721954971536, 3.0589644833873666],
                    [101.6671948756873, 3.0589975933496878],
                    [101.6671506985855, 3.0589613252294408],
]
Path_C= [
                    [101.66727417501791, 3.0590027072577914],
                    [101.6672681056769, 3.058961477349686],
                    [101.66721819457155, 3.058961780119454],
                    [101.66719440310052, 3.0589937049008178],
                    [101.66714811902433, 3.0589557068948929],
                    [101.66700933438982, 3.0591449764349572],
                    [101.66717343271783, 3.0592761332405467],
]
Path_D= [
                    [101.66727417501791, 3.0590027072577914],
                    [101.66727043087246, 3.0589587522319492],
                    [101.66721673964463, 3.0589590780046292],
                    [101.66719393051378, 3.0589898164519278],
                    [101.66714762932398, 3.0589518049327267],
]
```

The distance only valid between the path that are beside each others and not intersect. The first and last coordinates are also ignored. Below are my coding.

```
def distance_between_two_point(coordinate_1,coordinate_2):
    if coordinate_1==coordinate_2:
        return 0
    else:
        return hs.haversine(coordinate_1,coordinate_2)*1000

def find_gap:
   content=[]
   j=0
   for path in paths:
      for a in path:
      i = 1
            for b in path:
                    try:
                        a1 = a[i]
                        a2 = a[i+1]
                        b1 = a[i]
                        b2 = a[i+1]
                        offset1=distance_between_two_point(a1,b1)
                        offset2=distance_between_two_point(a2,b2)
                        if not ((offset1 <= 0.3 and offset1>=0.2) and (offset2 <= 0.3 and offset2 >= 0.2)):
                            content.append(['The line between path are closer/further away from each other']) 
                        i+=1
                    except:
                        pass
#Path B,C,D also have the same code as Path A
```

The problem is that its also log error for line that not besides each other.For example, Path A will return error with path B but will also return error between Path C and Path D. Note that the line may not be parallel. And thw line next to each other may be A,D or A,C and so on.

[image: The example of the lines]

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the problem: are you trying to find the **shortest distance** between any two lines and log an error if it is out of the allowed range (0.2-0.3) ?
Or does the allowed range apply all along the lines ? You can add a sketch to demonstrate.

Comment: the allowed range apply all along the lines. The applied lines is for the lines that are beside each other only. Its invalid when the line are intersect, but the line can be either parallel or skew within range.

Comment: So if you move a circle with a radius of 0.2mm along one line it can touch (be a tangent of) but never intersect with any line. Similarly, if you move a circle with a radius of 0.3mm along one line it should always intersect or be a tangent of any adjacent line.

Comment: Yeah. When you put it that way. It is. But how can i identify which part of line that is within that range?. Im sorry, i forgot to tell you that each line has it own id and i have to log the error when its out of bound

Comment: If you implies that i ca use the circle and line intersect formula, I think it not gonna work because the coordinates are in latitude and longitude. Thus, the distances differs when i use y=mx+c and haversine package of python.

Comment: I see in the "Incorrect scenario" that the distance is measured along a non-perpendicular line. I wonder why and how is it measured.

Comment: That is mistake on my part. I think that can be ignored as it complicated the situation to calculate the distance. For parallel line, calculations can be made along a perpendicular-line, and the skew line can be made from the start of the line until the end of it. The main problem in this code is that i can't figured our how to differ the line that are beside and not intercept each other.

Comment: I can't help with Python. Maybe [this](https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/matplotlib.path/Path/intersects_path/python-path-intersects_path-method-examples.html) can help